# please suggest code in R to create daily series by using ts command

Tags: r, time-series

I have a series for the daily temperature.

Date start from `2 February 1917` (`1917-02-02`) and end `2 March 1917` (`1917-03-02`). I need to create an object for daily series, please suggest `ts` command for daily series. I am using the following command:

```
ts(mydata$temp, frequency = 365, start=c(1917-02-02), end=c(1917-03-02))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you are supposed to write dates in ts.

You need to write a numeric vector of length two:

- first number is the number of periods (in your case the year)
- second number is the number of instant passed in the period (the number of days of the year).

To ease up the transformation I created for you a function that creates that vector from a date.

```
date_to_dayyear <- function(x){
  
  x <- as.Date(x)
  eval(parse(text = format(x, "c(%Y, %j)")))
  
}

ts(mydata$temp, frequency = 365,
   start = date_to_dayyear("1917-02-02"),
   end = date_to_dayyear("1917-03-02"))
```

Bear in mind that if you use daily time series the actual frequency is 365.25

---

Plot example.

```
set.seed(1)
plot(ts(rnrom(29), frequency = 365,
   start = date_to_dayyear("1917-02-02"),
   end = date_to_dayyear("1917-03-02")))
```

[image]

On the X axis, the number are difficult to interpret.
1917 is the year. The decimal numbers represent the fraction of the year that has passed: 1/365 each step.

I can understand that it is complicated to read.

---

Objects created with `ts` can be difficult to handle.

If you feel more confident working with dataframes, you can try to use [`tsibble`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tsibble/vignettes/intro-tsibble.html) as working environment.

Try:

```
library(tsibble)

set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(temp = rnorm(29),
                     date = seq.Date(as.Date("1917-02-02"), 
                                     as.Date("1917-03-02"), 
                                     by = "day"))


mydata <- as_tsibble(mydata, index = "date")
```

Also, to plot your data, you can rely on `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata) + geom_line(aes(x = date, y = temp))
```

[image]

Here you have no interpretation problem.

Once you have a tsibble you can perform transformations on your data like you would do with [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and you can forecast your time series if needed with some simple commands.
Check out: [fable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/vignettes/fable.html)

Comment: if I plot date wise time series for the above timeseries<-ts(mydata$temp, frequency = 365,
   start = date_to_dayyear("1917-02-02"),
   end = date_to_dayyear("1917-03-02")) using  plot(timeseries) it is not showing date wise time series plot. Suggest me how I can get the plot.